# Is it possible to import XML or JSON data from a table within a Word online document into Apps Script website as an HTML table?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, web-applications, ms-word, onedrive

I am building a web app using Apps Script.
In this web app I have a table that needs to be populated from a table in a Word doc in OneDrive.
This document is updated regularly, so I would prefer to programmatically update the content of the html table in Apps Script.
Is this possible?
If so, can anyone give me guidance as to how to accomplish this?

I've started looking into importing xml from a url, but I'm not sure that I'm on the right track.

Comment: https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-google-apps-script#stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the spelling correction. Are you referring to a specific article at that link?

Comment: Read it.  He has a OneDriveApp.

Comment: Thank you his article on his OneDriveApp seems helpful. That may be the route I go. [https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/OnedriveApp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to incorporate the following steps

- Read your data into a Google Apps function, e.g. with `OneDriveApp` as recommended by Cooper
- Use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) to call the Apps Script function from you `html` file
- Incorporate a [Web Polling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function that updates your html table with fresh contents in desired intervals

Sample:

> code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
function getFreshData(){
  //read here your Word Doc data, e.g. with One DriveApp and store it e.g. in an array
  ...
  return myDataArray;
}
```

> index.html

```
...
<body onload="polling()">
...
  <script>
    function polling(){
      setInterval(myFunction,2000);  //chose how often you want your table
     }
    function myFunction(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFreshData();        
    }
    function onSuccess(myDataArray){
      // Create a html table with the freshly obtained myDataArray from the Word Doc
     ...
    }
  </script>
...
```