# Dynamic (not frozen) coloring of image parts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I need your expertise to create a performance dashboard. Let's say I'm a car manufacturer. As the boss of this wonderful company, I need to have an overall idea of my manufacturing process.
My proposal would be to add on the dashboard a background image with my product:
[image]

How can I apply some layers to dynamically update the status of each work item (door, wheels ...), eg:
[image]

In this example, the boss will need to focus on the front doors of this beautiful car!

So now, some context. I would like to do some Google Apps Script / Javascript in order to update the colors (fixed colors: red/amber/green) on each part of the image, embedded on a site. The code should read the data somewhere during loading of the page (eg. in a google sheet or other DB) and to apply the right canvas/layers or any good idea you could suggest. Must have, associate links on each part of this image to drill down on each topic.

Which direction do you advise me to take?

Comment: While I like your question and would love to answer it, I'm afraid though this is not the place to ask 'what's-the-best-way-to-do-...' type-of
questions. As you might know you should ask a question on a specific coding problem e.g. if you tried to solve the problem
on your own and ran into trouble. To give you a little hint, you might read the status of each development stage from a simple textfile and tint overlaying svg elements with the appropriate color.

Comment: As a general hint: Apps Script Web Apps are very useful to link serverside contents (from Google Sheets) with client side (you image embedded in a Website): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: @obscure thank you for your kind feedback. I'm exploring the SVG direction and seems to be the right way.

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, I'm already familiar of Apps Script Web Apps and would like to do this stuff using GAS & deploy as web app.

Comment: As @obscure pointed out, this is not the place for general questions, but I provided you in my answer a general workflow to implement your request. I suggest you to try to write a code following this workflow and if you get stuck somewhere - post a question with your code specifying the specific problem you encounter. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### General workflow with Apps Script:

- Create a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).
- Implement in the .gs file (serverside) of the Web App a function that would pull and return data from your spreadsheet (the color values to be assigned to each car part)
- In the `html` file of the Web App, call the serverside function with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).
- Implement a [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) function with parameters that would use the data pulled from the serverside in a JS function.
- The JS function can create / modify the [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of your website assigning to your image the retrieved values for the colors.
- Embed the [URL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) of your WebApp into your Webpage.
- The data will be refreshed when refreshing your Webpage. Alternatively you can implement [Web Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615146/11599789) to refresh the data automatically in specified time intervals.