# Simultaneous Users in a Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a scoreboard web app that would keep track of the score for 2 teams.  How can I make it to where multiple users can use the app simultaneously and both teams can see the same score?  Currently, if I have 2 instances of the app open in a browser they will not reflect the same score when one is incremented.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("btn-sub-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
      Counter('s1');
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("btn-add-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
      Counter('a1');
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("btn-sub-2").addEventListener("click", function() {
      Counter('s2');
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("btn-add-2").addEventListener("click", function() {
      Counter('a2');
    }, false);
  });
  function Counter(val) {
    var score_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML);
    var score_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML);
    
    
    
    if (val=='s1' && score_1>0) {
      score_1--;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML = score_1;
    } else if (val=='a1') {
      score_1++;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML = score_1;
    } else if (val=='s2' && score_2>0) {
      score_2--;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML = score_2;
    } else if (val=='a2') {
      score_2++;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML = score_2;
    }

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    
    <?!= include("8-general-css"); ?>
    <?!= include("8-landscape-css"); ?>
    <?!= include("8-portrait-css"); ?>

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="team-1-container">
        <label class="lbl-team blk-text font-header" id="lbl-team-1">Team 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="player-1-container">
        <select class="browser-default player-select font-opt" id="player-opt-1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Player 1</option>
          <?!= players;?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="stats-1-container">
        <div class="lbl-elo-container">
          <label class="lbl-elo blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-elo-1">ELO: </label>
          <label class="lbl-elo-val blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-elo-val-1">-</label>
        </div>
        <div class="lbl-win-container">
          <label class="lbl-win blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-win-1">Win Prob: </label>
          <label class="lbl-win-val blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-win-val-1">-%</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="player-3-container">
        <select class="browser-default player-select font-opt" id="player-opt-3">
          <option value="">Player 3</option>
          <?!= players;?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-1-container">
        <button class="btn-sub font-btn" id="btn-sub-1"><span>-</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="score-1-container">
        <label class="lbl-score blk-text font-score" id="lbl-score-1">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="add-1-container">
        <button class="btn-add font-btn" id="btn-add-1">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="reset-container">
        <button class="btn-reset-submit font-reset-submit" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
      <div class="submit-container">
        <button class="btn-reset-submit font-reset-submit" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-2-container">
        <button class="btn-sub font-btn" id="btn-sub-2">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="score-2-container">
        <label class="lbl-score blk-text font-score" id="lbl-score-2">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="add-2-container">
        <button class="btn-add font-btn" id="btn-add-2">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="player-2-container">
        <select class="browser-default player-select font-opt" id="player-opt-2">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Player 2</option>
          <?!= players;?>
        </select>
      </div> 
      <div class="stats-2-container">
        <div class="lbl-elo-container">
          <label class="lbl-elo blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-elo-2">ELO: </label>
          <label class="lbl-elo-val blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-elo-val-2">-</label>
        </div>
        <div class="lbl-win-container">
          <label class="lbl-win blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-win-2">Win Prob: </label>
          <label class="lbl-win-val blk-text font-stats" id="lbl-win-val-2">-%</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="player-4-container">
        <select class="browser-default player-select font-opt" id="player-opt-4">
          <option value="">Player 4</option>
          <?!= players;?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="team-2-container">
        <label class="lbl-team blk-text font-header" id="lbl-team-2">Team 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <?!= include("8-ball-js"); ?>
    <?!= include("8-ball-swipe-score"); ?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably consider using Firebase / Firestore for providing real-time updates.

Comment: Poll from client side...

Comment: Don't just re-ask a closed question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288945/multiple-users-in-a-google-apps-script-web-app

Comment: [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615146/11599789) for polling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Users in a Google Apps Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288945/multiple-users-in-a-google-apps-script-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

All of your event Listeners point to this function.

```
function Counter(val) {
    var score_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML);
    var score_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML);
    if (val=='s1' && score_1>0) {
      score_1--;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML = score_1;
    } else if (val=='a1') {
      score_1++;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-1").innerHTML = score_1;
    } else if (val=='s2' && score_2>0) {
      score_2--;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML = score_2;
    } else if (val=='a2') {
      score_2++;
      document.getElementById("lbl-score-2").innerHTML = score_2;
    }

  }
```

But the function is not communicating with the server via google.script.run. And there are no forms for a submission. How do you expect the server to do anything if you don't communicate with it?